# Double Asset folder in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a working platform using Vue.js and a "static" folder that has most of my images, however I do want to add another assets folder so I can integrate my old software to this new one. However the images on my old one are in a "assets/images/products/" folder, & i need to be able to keep this path and the static path so none the new software or old one will break.

I have tried using double assets, importing a new endpoint and removing the static all together but nothing worked my system kept crashing through each time

This is my index.js:

```
index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

// Paths
assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
assetsPublicPath: '/',
```

and how i want the new images:

```
background-image: url(/assets/images/products/banner.png)
```

I am having trouble adding double assetsSubDirectory any help?

Here is an image of my folders:[image]

Comment: You forgot to add the 2nd image

Comment: @AliBahrami I did my folders as an example to see if i can even access assets/banner.png but I couldnt, any ideas?